# How do I use a JavaScript string in Razor?

Tags: javascript, razor

I want to use `Html.Raw()` for danish characters.

The JavaScript `item` can't be used in the `Razor`'s Html.Raw(), or what?

Error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'item'.

How do I solve this?

```
var tbody = "";
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var item = result[i];

    // Titel, Type
    tbody = tbody + '<tr>' + 
        '<td>' + '@(Html.Raw(item.Title))' + '</td>' + // <-- Cannot resolve symbol 'item'
        '<td>' + item.Type + '</td>' +
        + '</tr>';
}
$('#AttachmentTable tbody').append(tbody);
```

Comment: You can't razor is processed on server side and javascript is client side so when razor is rendering the page it knows nothing about the javascript code.

Comment: Why do you need `@(Html.Raw(...))` and don't use it directly -> you are writting HTML code! How is created `item.Title` : if this is generated from server side, you can call `Html.Raw` at this moment...

Comment: Item.Title contains danish letters like 'æøå' that gives a "?" in html.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. First understand the execution process of the page. 
On the **.chtml** page first Razor engine will parse whole page. 
Afterwards page load javascript will start its execution.

Now in your scenario while Razor engine parsing the page, it will now find **item** at all and will raise the error.

I think there is no need to use **@(Html.Raw(item.Title))**.
insted use directly **item.Title** 
so your final statement will be following:

```
  tbody = tbody + '<tr>' + 
    '<td>' + item.Title + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + item.Type + '</td>' +
    + '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't do this. Razor Engine loads first as server side code and then javascript is loaded on the client. Try using AJAX, pass your data to a controller and then process it from your underlying view, assuming you use ASP.NET MVC.
Just to clarify, the opposite is plausible, i mean to use razor code into javascript code.

**Edit:**
I can't comment on your question so I edit my answer:
You said: "Item.Title contains danish letters like 'æøå' that gives a "?" in html"
As Sujit Patil suggested, you don't need @Html.Raw, but pure javascript to achieve your goals. So use item.Title but...
You must set your meta charset in your document head to ISO-8859-1. Like this: 
`<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />`. I have tried this and it's working!